# How can I generate copies of a sheet, changing a cell value each time with a loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new with this drivesheets thing, but its great!  I have worked with Excel and Vba and I'm very excited to see this whole new world.

**Here is my problem:**  In Excel, I have file with a "template".  This template is linked to data that changes depending on a cell value.  For example, in cell `K26` there is a key number; if its value is `1`, the template will show you the information related with `1`. If it is `2`, it will show you the information related with `2` and so on.  There's a list of the numbers that I want to generate, so when I run the code the template will add a new sheet, copy its current values and paste them in the new sheet, rename the sheet from "SheetX" to the value of cell `K26` and then continue with the next row.

**Question**: I want to do the same in drivesheets, but dont know how to start.

My template sheet is called "Generador", and the current registry is in cell `K26` (this would be the sheet's name too).  The range I want to copy is from `A1` to `I67`.  If it possible, I would like to have a new workbook, and in this workbook create all the sheets of the list.  The list can be anywhere in the "List" sheet.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My code so far:
based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124604/google-script-duplicate-and-rename-sheets-based-on-list)

```
function createEmployeeSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   // Get the range of cells that store employee data.
  var ssLista = ss.getSheetByName("Lista");
  var rgEData = ssLista.getRange(2,1);
  var eData=rgEData.getValue();//número de registros
  var employeeDataRange = ssLista.getRange(2,1,eData,1);//Nombres de hoja empezando en columna 1 desde fila 2
  var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Generador');

  for (var i=0; i < employeeObjects.length; i++) {
     // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);
      // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
      // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.
        if (sheet) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + employeeObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {
           template.getRange("K3").offset(0,0).setValue(employeeObjects[i]);
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);

           }
        }
  return;

  i = 0;
}
```

I have managed to generate every sheet, change K3 of the template value and rename it.  I'm missing two things:

I'm still getting an error: when the code starts generating the sheets it goes on and doesn't stop in the last row of the "List" sheet.  For example, I have 3 rows with values, and when the loop goes for the 4 it shows the error line, because it can't name the sheets with nothing (null).

The other thing is that I want to generate the sheets in a new workbook, not in the current one.  Is there a way that these sheets can be created in a new one? Considering that information is linked with formulas, so it should be values only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The getValues() function returns a 2D array Objec[][]

```
function createEmployeeSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shLista = ss.getSheetByName('Lista');
  var rgEData = shLista.getRange(1,3);
  var eData=rgEData.getValue();//the number of names I think
  var employeeDataRange = ssLista.getRange(2,1,eData,1);//Sheet names in column1 starting from row2
  var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();//sheet names in column 0
  var template=ss.getSheetByName('Generador');//template
  for (var i=0;i< employeeObjects.length; i++) {
    if(!ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i][0])){
      template.getRange("K3").setValue(employeeObjects[i][0]);
      var sheet=ss.insertSheet(employeeObjects[i][0], {template:template});
    }
  }
}
```

- [Insert Sheet(Sheetname, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname-options)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

This code has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks.  Although your code seems to solutionate the dinamyc range problem, I still can't get to change the cell value in the Generator sheet K3, that is the linked cell that changes all the values showed.

Right now, I get X copies of my Generator sheet without any change, and all the created sheets are named "Copy X of Generator".  I want the loop to go from cell A2 to A(x) of sheet "List", and change the K3 cell from "Generator" each time; then, create a sheet with current information and rename it with the current registry.  Its frustrating because in VBA its really simple.